# PyEval_CallObject failing in loop occasionally

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I am struggling a bit with the Python C API.  I am calling a python method to do some game AI at about 60hz.  It works *most* of the time but every second or so the call to PyEval_CallObject results in a NULL return value. If I correctly detect the error and continue looping, all is well for the next second or so, whereupon the error occurs again.

I suspect I am doing something wrong with ref counting but I can't figure out what it is:

```
int script_do_ai(struct game_data_t* gd)
{

    PyObject *pAiModule, *pResult;

    float result=0.0;
    pResult = NULL;

    pAiModule = PyImport_Import(PyString_FromString("ai_script"));
```

Yeah, I'm importing the the module every iteration. Is that necessary? If I store pAiModule as a global, I get a hard crash after about a second.

```
    pResult = PyEval_CallObject(PyObject_GetAttrString(pAiModule, "do_ai"),
                               Py_BuildValue("f", gd->important_float))  
    if (pResult != NULL)
    {       
        PyArg_Parse(pResult, "f", &result);
        Py_DECREF(pResult);
        ConquerEnemies(result);  //you get the idea
    }
    else  //this happens every 75 or so iterations thru the loop
    {
       if (PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_SomeException))  //? not sure what to do here
       {
```

I haven't been able to find out how to extract the exception yet, either...without testing for *every* exception

```
       }
    }
```

Am I even close to doing this right? Like I said, it mostly works but I'd really like to understand why I am getting an error.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `PyImport_Import()` as often as you like, but you'll just keep getting the same module object back. Python caches imports. Also, instead of creating a new Python string and leaking the reference (and thus the object), you should just use `PyImport_ImportModule()`, which takes a `const char *`.

`PyImport_Import*()` return a new reference, though, you should call `Py_DECREF()` on it when you're done. Storing the module in a global should not be a problem, as long as you own a reference to it (which you do, here.)

In your call to `PyEval_CallObject()` you aren't checking the result of `Py_BuildValue()` for errors, and you're also not calling `Py_DECREF()` when you're done with it, so you're leaking that object as well.

In order to convert a Python float to a C double, you should probably just call `PyFloat_AsDouble()` instead of mucking about with `PyArg_Parse()` (and keep in mind to test for exceptions)

Down to the actual error handling: `PyErr_ExceptionMatches()` is only useful when you actually want to test if the exception matches something. If you want to know if an exception occurred, or get the actual exception object, `PyErr_Occurred()` is what you should call. It returns the current exception *type* (not the actual exception object) as a borrowed reference, or NULL if none is set. If you want to just print a traceback to stderr, `PyErr_Print()` and `PyErr_Clear()` are what you want to use. For more fine-grained inspection of the actual error in your code, `PyErr_Fetch()` gets you the current exception object and the traceback associated with it (it gets you the same information as `sys.exc_info()` in Python code.) All things considered you rarely want to get that deeply into the exception handling in C code.

Comment: +1 thanks...I figured if I inlined the call to Py_BuildValue it would take care of the leaky reference but perhaps not.

I'll see what PyErr_Fetch gives me on pyErr_Occurred

Comment: Alas, C is not garbage collected :) PyErr_Print() is quite convenient for printing exceptions, especially when debugging cases like this.

Comment: Yeah too much time in .NET-land for me.

Okay weird. I added "sys.stdout = open('CONOUT$', 'wt')" to my python script (to output to console...I'm in Win32) and everything started magically working. Bizarre.

Comment: FYI...I fixed the bug.  Turns out the loop I was running was not sync'd to 60hz...it was running the cpu at 100%.  I threw in a 10ms non-busy wait and all appears to be well.  It at least explains why adding console output 'fixed' the problem before...it was a timing issue. Couldn't have solved it without the above tips though...thanks!